# How to compute satellite coordinates (lat,long) given antenna's coordinates, angles and satellite height

Tags: position

Given an Earth station (antenna) coordinates (in lat,long) ant its Elevation (El) and Azimuth (Az), how to compute the satellite coordinates (lat,long), known its height?

For simplification purposes, the Earth can be considered as an sphere.

So its given:

```
Earth Radius = 6371000 meters
Satellite Height, in meters (perpendicular to the Earth's)

Station lat, long (as parameters)
Station height (0 = Zero, for simplification purposes)
Station Elevation (angle, radius or degrees)
Station Azimuth (angle, radius or degrees)
```

The problem can be shown in this two figures:
[image: Earth station and Satellite Schema]
[image: Earth station horizon plane]